# How to create a custom plugin to jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables, custom-controls

I'm planning to add a custom ordering plugin to JQuery Datatable like this one :
[image]
I have googled around, but cannot find a way to **display** the plugin, I only found the way to "code" the order by algorithm.

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a hidden column.

Comment: I dont quite understand the question. I see a `select2` select which facilitates an alternative way to sort columns. What is the plugin / extension? I guess you now make it visible by adding an element to the `dom` attribute, and then populate the select upon `initComplete`? (or something like that).  If you want to create a `orderSelect: true` stylish extension, then I would suggest you inspect other extensions to see how they are implemented.

Comment: yes, you're right I'm trying to manipulate the dom attribute. I'm planning to create an order flag, and it will be sent to server and processed accordingly, this is a bit different from datatable column ordering, where you can click any column and have the data ordered/sorted.